# Please help me turn off pinch zoom on Windows 10 touchpad (no options from driver)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, touchpad

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad S145 laptop with an ELAN touchpad. The touchpad works, but there appears to be no way to configure the touchpad. Normally this is found in the 'Additional Mouse Options' menu under 'Mouse' in the Devices options in the Windows settings. But there is no ELAN tab there (the last one is 'hardware'). I tried following [the instructions to set up Microsoft's Precision Touchpad drivers](https://www.howtogeek.com/325347/how-to-enable-microsofts-precision-touchpad-drivers-on-your-laptop/), which added the ELAN tab to the Additional Mouse Options, but rendered the touchpad unusuable due to an Error 10. Upon clicking 'update driver', the touchpad is working again but the ELAN tab has disappeared.

Since I don't have access to the drivers, is there any way I can turn off the INCREDIBLY ANNOYING pinch zoom (which I never use on a laptop anyway, except to correct the accidental use of it). It is SO frustrating. Is there any sort of a 'universal touchpad control' app or something (like a universal TV remote)?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem (I bougth same device) and I found a solution. Just download drivers from Microsoft Store: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/etdproperties/9pcfvjpq0frl